# Mount NFS on ARM based ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, mount, nfs, synology

I have a Synology NAS and I created a NFS share. I was using the official tutoral https://www.synology.com/de-de/knowledgebase/DSM/tutorial/File_Sharing/How_to_access_files_on_Synology_NAS_within_the_local_network_NFS

But now I cannot mount the NFS share on my ARM based ubuntu.

```
root@lubuntu:~# mount 192.168.1.100:/volume1/Mediacenter /mnt/Mediacenter
mount.nfs: No such device
```

I tried the following from https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NFS/Troubleshooting#Client-side_issues

```
lsmod | grep nfs
```

Output Empty

```
root@lubuntu:~# modprobe nfs
modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:556 kmod_search_moddep() could not open moddep file '/lib/modules/3.10.0/modules.dep.bin'
```

Can anybody help me please?

Comment: Ubuntu Version 14.04

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have had a simlar problem before, the solution I found was to actually mount the share at boot. This is done within fstab on Ubuntu. However, the best way to do this is to install 'cifs' (Common Internet File System), this allows you to mount Samba shares, and other Network file systems.

You can install CIFS using apt-get

```
sudo apt-get install cifs-utils
```

Then once installed you must edit '*/etc/fstab*' and add this line to the bottom of the file:

```
//ip_of_share/share_name /mount/location cifs defaults 0 0
```

This will allow the share to be mounted. If you are required to log in to the share then you can do this:

```
//ip_of_share/share_name /mount_location cifs credentials=/location,defaults 0 0
```

If you are required to log into the share, then you must add a credentials file. You can do this by using creating a new file using nano or your favorite editor:

```
sudo nano /location/of/credentials
```

Once created, the username and password nodes must be added:

```
username=username_of_share_user
password=password_of_share_user
```

To make your file credentials file as secure as possible you can use chmod to close the files access down to make it read only:

```
sudo chmod 400 /location/of/credentials
```

If you would like the share to be mounted under a specific user and group, you can use:

```
//ip_of_share/share_name /mount_location cifs credentials=/location,uid=user_id,gid=group_id,defaults 0 0
```

Then finally, you can either restart, or do:

```
sudo mount /mount/location
```

I hope this helps.